# Concatenating multiple data frames, ignoring row index in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have 3 different data frames that I would like to merge:

| Index | Year |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 2001 |
| 1 | 2002 |

| Index | VarA |
| --- | --- |
| 700 | x |
| 701 | y |

| Index | VarB |
| --- | --- |
| 700 | a |
| 701 | b |

so that they look like this:

| Index | Year | VarA | VarB |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2001 | x | a |
| 1 | 2002 | y | b |

when I use `pd.concat([df1,df2,df3])`, Var A and Var B line up with eachother but don't line up with the year.  Can somebody point me in the right direction?

Comment: if the index is different and meaningless, you have to reset it before concatenating

Comment: Thankyou! fixed with: df = df.reset_index(drop=True)

Comment: you might want to post it as an answer and accept later if you want. comments get deleted

Comment: Given that you just want new columns irrespective of the index, you could just do:

`df1['VarA'] = df2['VarA'].values` and `df1['VarB'] = df3['VarB'].values`

Answer (score 0):

Fixed with `df = df.reset_index(drop=True)`